# Difference between LogPlot and Plot[Log]

Tags: plotting, functions

I want to plot a function with `LogPlot[]`, but I got interested to see `Plot[Log[f],{t,...}}`, and I was surprised to see that with `LogPlot[]` the scale values of the function where in the `10^32`, while plotting the `Log[f]` gave me values up to 72. Why is it different if `LogPlot[]` must apply `Log[]` to `f` and then `Plot[]`?

Example using `Sin[t]`

[image]

Comment: `Log[x]` (without specifying a base) by default returns the natural log, while the scale on `LogPlot` is by default base-10.

Comment: @eyorble, it helps to know that. However, when doing `Plot[Log[10,Sin[t]],{t,0,2Pi}]` does not give me the same plot as the `LogPlot[]`

Comment: LogPlot doesn't take the logarithm of the function--it plots the function on a logarithmic scale.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's due to a misunderstanding of LogPlot.

Comment: Since the `Sin` function goes to zero at `0` and `2 Pi` (which cannot be shown on a log plot), the plots are arbitrarily setting the lower plot range to whatever value their respective algorithms consider "of likely interest". If you want the plots to reflect the some specific numeric values, specify the desired `PlotRange`.

Answer (score 1):

Amazingly the plotted curves are identical (V14.0.0):

```
Cases[Plot[Log[Sin[t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}], 
  p_List?MatrixQ /; Length[p] > 2 :> p, Infinity] == 
 Cases[LogPlot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}], 
  p_List?MatrixQ /; Length[p] > 2 :> p, Infinity]

(* True *)
```

The difference in what one sees has to do with scaled tick marks.